# mover elementos html usando javascript dependiendo de su posición en X

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un elemento con unas dimensiones determinadas y dentro de este se encuentra varios hijos de diferentes `width` que se salen del ancho del padre por lo que el padre tiene un `overflow-x: auto;`.
Cada uno de estos elementos son `relative` y contienen un elemento `absolute` en diversas posiciones.

Lo que deseo es que al presionar un botón me centre (si es posible) con respecto al eje X, el elemento absolute con respecto al padre, haciendo un scroll.

Por ejemplo: si se presiona el botón "centrar bola roja", el elemento flotante que se encuentra el el div con el fondo rojo se centra lo mejor posible. En este caso es imposible centrarlo ya que el scroll no da pero lleva el scroll hasta el principio.
En el caso de "centrar bola  azul" si puede darle scroll hasta estar en el centro, etc.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: gray;
}

.wrapper div {
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper div span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
}

.red span {
  top: 5px;
  left: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 700px;
}

.blue span {
  top: 100px;
  right: 255px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  width: 400px;
}

.green span {
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="red">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="green">
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>centrar bola roja</button>
<button>centrar bola azul</button>
<button>centrar bola verde</button>
```

Comment: Te faltó el código javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola creo que para poder lograr lo que deseas puedes añadirle lo siguiente.

```js
function centerElement(selector) {
  const element = document.querySelector(selector);
  const parentOfElement = element.parentElement;
  const { width, height } = parentOfElement.getBoundingClientRect();

  element.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth",
    block: "center",
    inline: "center",
  });
  element.style = `top: ${height / 2}px; left: ${width / 2}px`;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: gray;
}

.wrapper div {
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper div span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
}

.red span {
  top: 5px;
  left: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 700px;
}

.blue span {
  top: 100px;
  right: 255px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  width: 400px;
}

.green span {
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="centerElement('.red>span')">centrar bola roja</button>
<button onclick="centerElement('.blue>span')">centrar bola azul</button>
<button onclick="centerElement('.green>span')">centrar bola verde</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="red">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="green">
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).